# how do i loop through a json object from an api in vuejs?

Tags: json, vue.js

/*Dear All,
I would like to create a table from this API created JSON object, how can I use v-for in Vue js ?* design is not important I just cannot implement v-for in this case? the table should not be fancy just a plane html table/

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>meta</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>is private</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
      
    </table>
  
  </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items:''
    }
  },


  created() {
    axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/pages/`)
    .then(response => {
     
      this.items = response.data
    })
    
  }
}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: is your `response.data` an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML table:

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>meta</th>
          <th>title</th>
          <th>is private</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.meta.detail_url }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.is_private }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
async created() {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/pages/`
    );
    this.items = response.data.items;
  },
```

Comment: thanks babis95 but after this my table is empty :(, does it work on your end?

Comment: Please see edited code. Changed HTML to reflect API data keys. Changed your script to use async await (my preference)... you can continue with promises, it will work as well

Comment: thanks a lot babis95

Comment: babis95, how can I get json data with that code from a multiple pages api? like this: https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?format=api&page_size=12&type=5 , thank you for your trouble